# How to create a checklist with a bat file/batch script in the console window?

Tags: windows, batch-file, console

I'm looking to create a checklist in a console window to help users choose certain options they would like to install. This kind of output:

```
Please select options to install:
[x]Option 1
[ ]Option 2
>[x]Option 3
[x]Option 4
```

Where the user can move the cursor throughout the list and select the options.

I have a very, very vague idea of how I might do this code, testing with just two options. But if there is anyone who already has a solidified idea of how this would work and could share I would be very appreciative!

Test code for those who want to see it:

```
@echo off

call:main
end /b 0

:main
set /p choice= "Would you like to enable option one? (yes/no): "echo(
if %choice%==yes (
    set option1=1
)
if %choice%==no (
    set option1=0
)
call:mod1
set /p choice= "Would you like to enable option two? (yes/no): "echo(
if %choice%==yes (
    set option2=1
)
if %choice%==no (
    set option2=0
)
call:mod2

:mod1
if %option1%==1 (
echo [x] Option 1
)
if %option1%==0 (
echo [ ] Option 1
)

:mod2
if %option2%==1 (
echo [x] Option 1
)
if %option2%==0 (
echo [ ] Option 1
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%A in ('"prompt $H &echo on &for %%B in (1) do rem"') do set BS=%%A
set "getKeyMacro=powershell -noprofile "^
    while (-not (37..40+13).contains($x)) {^
        $x = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown').VirtualKeyCode^
    }^
    if ($x -eq 13) {^
    'enter'^
    }^
    ('left','up','right','down')[$x - 37]^
""

set "option1=0"
set "option2=0"
set "option3=0"
set "option4=0"
set "selected=1"
:select
cls
echo use ^<right^> arrow to continue, ^<up^> and ^<down^> to select, and ^<enter^> to toggle
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,4) DO (
set "display=[ ]"
if !option%%G! equ 1 set "display=[x]"
if %%G equ !selected! set "display=^>!display!
echo !display! Option %%G
)
FOR /F "delims==" %%G IN ('%getKeyMacro%') DO set "key=%%G"
if "%key%"=="up" set /a "selected-=1"
if "%key%"=="down" set /a "selected+=1"
if %selected% lss 1 set "selected=1"
if %selected% gtr 4 set "selected=4"
if "%key%"=="enter" goto toggle
if "%key%"=="right" goto OK
goto select

:toggle
set /a "option%selected%+=1"
set /a "option%selected%=!option%selected%!%%2"
goto select

:OK
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,4) DO (
if !option%%G! equ 1 (
echo %%G selected
)
)
pause
```

Note that this is very heavily dependent on Delayed Expansion, so you might want to read up on it [here](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Second note: this needs powershell so you can use up and down arrow keys to select options, enter to toggle currently selected option, and right arrow to continue.

**EDIT**

Updated version, this allows you to set the display names for the options, but you need to specify the amount of options aswell:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%A in ('"prompt $H &echo on &for %%B in (1) do rem"') do set BS=%%A
set "getKeyMacro=powershell -noprofile "^
    while (-not (37..40+13).contains($x)) {^
        $x = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown').VirtualKeyCode^
    }^
    if ($x -eq 13) {^
    'enter'^
    }^
    ('left','up','right','down')[$x - 37]^
""

set "option1=0"
set "option2=0"
set "option3=0"
set "option4=0"
set "option1name=Install thing 1"
set "option2name=Do thing 2"
set "option3name=Execute thing 3"
set "option4name=Run thing 4"
set "maxOptions=4"
set "selected=1"
:select
cls
echo use ^<right^> arrow to continue, ^<up^> and ^<down^> to select, and ^<enter^> to toggle
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,%maxOptions%) DO (
set "display=[ ]"
if !option%%G! equ 1 set "display=[x]"
if %%G equ !selected! set "display=^>!display!
echo !display! !option%%Gname!
)
FOR /F "delims==" %%G IN ('%getKeyMacro%') DO set "key=%%G"
if "%key%"=="up" set /a "selected-=1"
if "%key%"=="down" set /a "selected+=1"
if %selected% lss 1 set "selected=1"
if %selected% gtr %maxOptions% set "selected=!%maxOptions%!"
if "%key%"=="enter" goto toggle
if "%key%"=="right" goto OK
goto select

:toggle
set /a "option%selected%+=1"
set /a "option%selected%=!option%selected%!%%2"
goto select

:OK
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,%maxOptions%) DO (
if !option%%G! equ 1 (
echo %%G selected
)
)
pause
```

**EDIT #2**

Now uses the for loop by @Aacini to initiate the variables so this only needs to happen once, and so there is no need for a manual maxoption any more:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "getKeyMacro=powershell -noprofile "^
    while (-not (37..40+13).contains($x)) {^
        $x = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown').VirtualKeyCode^
    }^
    if ($x -eq 13) {^
    'enter'^
    }^
    ('left','up','right','down')[$x - 37]^
""

set "num=0"
for %%a in ("Install thing 1"
            "Do thing 2"
            "Execute thing 3"
            "Run thing 4") do (
   set /A num+=1
   set "option!num!=0"
   set "option!num!name=%%~a"
)
set "maxOptions=%num%"
set "selected=1"
:select
cls
echo use ^<right^> arrow to continue, ^<up^> and ^<down^> to select, and ^<enter^> to toggle
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,%maxOptions%) DO (
set "display=[ ]"
if !option%%G! equ 1 set "display=[x]"
if %%G equ !selected! set "display=^>!display!
echo !display! !option%%Gname!
)
FOR /F "delims==" %%G IN ('%getKeyMacro%') DO set "key=%%G"
if "%key%"=="up" set /a "selected-=1"
if "%key%"=="down" set /a "selected+=1"
if %selected% lss 1 set "selected=1"
if %selected% gtr %maxOptions% set "selected=!%maxOptions%!"
if "%key%"=="enter" goto toggle
if "%key%"=="right" goto OK
goto select

:toggle
set /a "option%selected%+=1"
set /a "option%selected%=!option%selected%!%%2"
goto select

:OK
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,%maxOptions%) DO (
if !option%%G! equ 1 (
echo %%G selected
)
)
pause
```

Comment: This is perfect! How would I go about modifying this so that I can change the options from "Option 1" to "Install program x"?

Comment: Edited so you can now specify display names.

Comment: Why do you define the `BS` variable if you don't use it?

Comment: That is a line from an older batch-script I created that I used the powershell code from that I forgot to delete.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the text for the options
set "num=0"
for %%a in ("First option"
            "Second option"
            "Third option"
            "Fourth option") do (
   set /A num+=1
   set "msg[!num!]=%%~a"
   set "opt[!num!]= "
)
set "digits=0123456789"

:select
   (cls
   echo Press digit to mark/unmark options, or X to end
   echo/
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%num%) do echo !digits:~%%i,1!. [!opt[%%i]!]  !msg[%%i]!
   )
   choice /C !digits:~1,%num%!X /N > NUL
   if %errorlevel% gtr %num% goto endSelect
   set "sel=%errorlevel%"
   if "!opt[%sel%]!" equ "X" (set "opt[%sel%]= ") else set "opt[%sel%]=X"
goto select
:endSelect

echo/
echo/
for /L %%i in (1,1,%num%) do (
   if "!opt[%%i]!" equ "X" (
      echo %%i selected
   )
)
```

Comment: Would you mind if I edited my answer so it uses the for loop you use here to initiate the variables? I'll give credit of course.

Comment: @DennisvanGils: Please, do! **`;)`**